# Node Express can't figure out how to update user details

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Okay so once the user logs in, i am storing their details in req.user. The user should then be able to edit their details (fistname, lastname, email) in a form rendered with the /profile route as seen below:

```
    app.get('/profile', checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
      res.render('profile.ejs', req.user);
    })
```

Here is the form:

```
<form class="form__inputs" action="/update-profile" method="post">
  <div class="form__input">
    <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" value="<%=firstname%>" required />
    <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form__input">
    <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" value="<%=lastname%>" required />
    <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form__input form__email">
      <input id="email" name="email" type="email" value="<%=email%>" required />
      <label for="email">Email</label>
  </div>
  <button class="form__button" type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

After submitting the form the i want the user to be redirected to the /update-profile route, where i can perform an update to the database (MySQL).

```
app.put('/update-profile', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params)
  console.log(req.body)
  res.redirect('/')
})
```

However I'm recieving a "Cannot POST /update-profile" error.

I was just going to use the user_id stored in req.user, and new user data (firstname, lastname, email) stored in req.body.params to update the database, but i've clearly gotten a bit mixed up with my routes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Typo?  The form is sending a POST request, but the server-side code is expecting a PUT request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are listening to a PUT request in your express app, but sending a POST.

```js
app.post('/update-profile', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params)
    console.log(req.body)
    res.redirect('/')
});
```

If you change your code to this, it should work.

Comment: That worked thank you! Can i ask, what is the purpose of app.put, if we can't set the method attribute of our forms to "PUT"? It has to be app.post?

Comment: They both have different use cases. Put is usually used to create a resource and post to modify it. You can learn more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods